# Nginx reverse proxy with docker-compose

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to use nginx with docker-compose.
My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  webserver:
    build: ./webserver
    ports:
      - 8000:80

  demo1:
    build: ./demo
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: npm start 3000

  demo2:
    build: ./demo
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    command: npm start 3001
```

My Nginx config file nginx.conf looks like this:

```
http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream demo1 {
      server demo1:3000;
    }

    upstream demo2 {
      server demo2:3001;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://demo1;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }

        location /test {
            proxy_pass         http://demo2;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

After running `docker-compose up` I can access demo1 with http://localhost:8000, but I can't access demo2 with http://localhost:8000/test. When trying I get `Cannot GET /test`.

Do you know why? Can I make it work with different paths of the same server pointing to different services?